# PostgreSQL full text search building GIN index

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

I am trying to do full text search in a column `rss` (django text field) of a table named `nsviews_aptdisplayrow`. It is very slow because `rss` is very long. So I want to add a GIN index to rss.
I can't find a way to add index in django so I do it like this in PostgreSQL directly.

```
CREATE INDEX "rss_vector" ON "nsviews_aptdisplayrow" USING gin(to_tsvector('english', 'rss'));
```

I seach in `rss` like this:

```
finalquery = SearchQuery('<li>Furnished')
vector = SearchVector('rss') 
qs = qs.annotate(search=vector).filter(search=finalquery)
```

Actually I didn't see any improvement in speed. Do you know the reason? Is there any wrong what I did? Thanks!

Comment: What is the SQL and the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output?

Comment: Sorry I am new, do you mean I should use `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` command and see the output? and what is `what is the SQL` means?

Comment: Well, your code will produce an SQL query that is sent to the database. Prepend it with `EXPLAIN ...` as indicated above and post the result.